# How to on python server just that word which is encoded with urlencode function to decode

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have just one word (parameter which contains user's name sent from c++ client ) encoded with urlEncode function (to support utf characters). How to on python server just that word to get back ( to decode) ?

I tried with urllib but it doesn't work

```
import urllib
urllib.unquote('%C5%BDeljko').decode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that it doesn't work? When your code completes its course without any warning/error, then it means that it obviously works. What result are you expecting? When the result you are seeking is the decoded word, then, your code works fine.

For illustration:

```
import urllib
urllib.unquote('%C5%BDeljko').decode('utf8')
```

outputs

```
u'\u017deljko'
```

Whereas,

```
import urllib
print urllib.unquote('%C5%BDeljko').decode('utf8')
```

outputs

```
Željko
```

Obviously, different outputs are there depending on how you process/interpret them.